# Add a new row to pageblock table when clicking on a button

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, button

I want to add rows to a pageblocktable when clicking on a button. My current controller displays all the rows so I want to make it work to add rows when clicking on a button. 1st row should display anyway and all the other rows beneath should be added when clicking on the button. Help on this would be much appreciated.

My controller

```
public with sharing class MultipleContactsController {

    public List<Contact> Contacts {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> ContactsToInsert {get; set;}

    public MultipleContactsController() {
        contacts = new List<Contact>();

        for(integer a=0; a<15; a++){
            Contact newContact = new Contact();
            contacts.add(newContact);
        }
    }

    public PageReference Save(){
        for(Contact c : Contacts){
            if(isValid(c))
                ContactsToInsert.add(c);
        }
        if(ContactsToInsert.size() > 0)
            insert ContactsToInsert;

        return null;
    }

    public boolean isValid(Contact c){
        boolean retVal = false;

        if(c.LastName !=null && c.Phone !=null)
            retVal = true;

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

My Visualforce page

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" controller="MultipleContactsController">

<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Contacts}" var="contact">

            <apex:column headerValue="First Name"><apex:inputField value="{!contact.FirstName}"/></apex:column> 
            <apex:column headerValue="Last Name"><apex:inputField value="{!contact.LastName}"/></apex:column>
            <!-- <apex:column headerValue="Account Name"><apex:inputField value="{!contact.Account.Name}"/></apex:column> -->
            <apex:column headerValue="Job Title"><apex:inputField value="{!contact.Title}"/></apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Email"><apex:inputField value="{!contact.Email}"/></apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Mobile"><apex:inputField value="{!contact.Phone}"/></apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Phone"><apex:inputField value="{!contact.Phone}"/></apex:column>


        </apex:pageBlockTable>


        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" title="Save" value="Save" immediate="true"/>

    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Here is a link http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/12/adding-and-deleting-rows-dynamically-in.html on similar topic.

Comment: This is very helpful !